# What am I missing about ngFor and the AsyncPipe?

Tags: angular, observable

This looks to me like it should work, but I get a template error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

The template:

```
<div class="block-header">
    <h2>{{ policyName }}</h2>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let p of policies | async" class="card event-card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h2>{{ p.title }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body card-padding">
        <div [markdown]="p.description"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The component:

```
export class PoliciesComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string = 'policies';
  //public policies: Policy[];
  public policies: Observable<Policy>;

  constructor(
    private policyService: PolicyService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.route.params is an observable of the child (category) routes under /policies
    this.route.params.subscribe((p: Params) => this.loadPolicies(p['category']))
  }

  loadPolicies(category: string): void {
    let policyCategory = PolicyCategory.ClubPolicy;
    if (category === 'rules') {
      policyCategory = PolicyCategory.LocalRule;
    } else if (category === 'handicaps') {
      policyCategory = PolicyCategory.Handicaps;
    }
    this.policies = this.policyService.loadPolicies(policyCategory);
    // this.policies = [];
    // this.policyService.loadPolicies(policyCategory).subscribe(p => this.policies.push(p))
  }
}
```

The service:

```
loadPolicies(category: PolicyCategory): Observable<Policy> {
    return this.dataService.getApiRequest('policies')
        .mergeAll() // turn Observable<any> where any=collection into Observable
        .map((p: any) => new Policy().fromJson(p))
        .filter((policy: Policy) => policy.category === category)
}
```

With the replacement code (in comments in the component), everything works, but then I will have to unsubscribe from the subscriptions. I feel like I'm doing this right, but my browser disagrees.

What am I misunderstanding about how async works with an Observable?

Comment: Can you try it without the filter?

Comment: try to remove the mergeAll() operation.

Comment: mergeAll() is a mistake here. I should return an Observable<Policy[]>, and the async filter will work. But I also intend to rework the service to be closer to what I posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question "what am I misunderstanding?" is, way too much.

Most fundamentally, I think, is understanding the role of a service when trying to do a more reactive style of programming. It should do more than act as a pass through.

Based on reading [this post](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services) by Cory Rylan, I've come to the conclusion that my services should manage the data from an api quite differently. The Overview section towards the end is especially worth reading.

So while I haven't reworked the service in the original post, I do have what I think is a good pattern to use for CRUDdy services. The service has a data store which my component subscribes to. The actions mutate that data store, and with the miracle of observables, they are automatically updated when the store changes as a result of those actions.

Replace "ProfilerJob" with whatever object you are managing:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfilerJobService {

    private resource: string = 'profile';

    private _jobs: BehaviorSubject<ProfilerJob[]>;
    private store: {
        items: ProfilerJob[]
    };

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
        this.store = {
            items: []
        };
        this._jobs = <BehaviorSubject<ProfilerJob[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
    }

    get jobs(): Observable<ProfilerJob[]> {
        return this._jobs.asObservable();
    }

    selectJob(id: string): Observable<ProfilerJob> {
        if (id === 'new') {
            return Observable.of(new ProfilerJob());
        }
        return this._jobs.map(jobs => {
            let job = jobs.find(item => item.id === id);
            return _.clone(job);
        });
    }

    loadJobs(filter: JobFilter = null): void {
        let url = this.resource;
        let params: any;
        if (filter) {
            url = url + '/search';
            params = filter.toSearchApi();
        }
        this.dataService.getData(url, params).subscribe(data => {
            this.store.items.length = 0;
            data.forEach((d: any) => this.store.items.push(new ProfilerJob().fromJson(d)));
            this._jobs.next(_.cloneDeep(this.store).items);
        });
    }

    loadJob(id: string): void {
        this.dataService.getData(`${this.resource}/${id}`).subscribe(json => {
            let found = false;
            this.store.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                if (item.id === json.id) {
                    this.store.items[index] = new ProfilerJob().fromJson(json);
                    found = true;
                }
            });
            if (!found) {
                this.store.items.push(new ProfilerJob().fromJson(json));
            }
            this._jobs.next(_.cloneDeep(this.store).items);
        });
    }

    addJob(job: ProfilerJob): Observable<void> {
        return this.dataService.postData(this.resource, job.toJson())
            .do((json: any) => {
                this.loadJob(json.id);
            });
    }

    updateJob(job: ProfilerJob): Observable<void> {
        return this.dataService.putData(`${this.resource}/${job.id}`, job.toJson())
            .do(() => {
                this.loadJob(job.id);
            });
    }

    deleteJob(job: ProfilerJob): Observable<void> {
        return this.dataService.deleteData(`${this.resource}/${job.id}`)
            .do(() => {
                let idx = this.store.items.findIndex(j => j.id === job.id);
                this.store.items.splice(idx, 1);
                this._jobs.next(_.cloneDeep(this.store).items);
            });
    }
}
```